# If other objects can modify an attribute, is it truly private?

Tags: object-oriented, python

I am working in Python so attribute privacy isn't enforced. I have a `Library` class that stores a list of library `Items` related to that library. I want to be able to access the library Items through the Library class. Right now I accomplish that by returning the "private" items attribute. However, any class would then be able to modify that list. Would I need to make a "deep copy" of these in order for the `items` attribiute to be truly private? Should I just make the attribute public?

```
class Library():
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self._hours = []
        self._items = []
        self._name = name
    
    def get_hours_str(self):
        ret = ""
        for day in self._hours:
            ret += day + '\n'
        return ret

    def get_items(self):
        return self._items
```

Comment: It really depends what you are trying to accomplish. I would say it is definitely suspicious though. Why do you want access to this list? Perhaps you can provide something weaker that allows you to do what you want and without the cost of a copy. For instance, if you just want to iterate through the list, provide an iterator of the list rather than the list itself.

Comment: Thanks for your input @JustSomeGuy. I will be iterating through the items so an iterator makes sense.

Comment: If you’re looking to protect your _items array from becoming aliased and received unintended external modifications, you can use a wrapper object which exposes a read-only view of the array’s contents, but without copying it. This looks promising: https://pypi.org/project/immutable-views/  The tricky part is how to handle nested structures. E.g. if you have an array of dictionaries, and you make an immutable view of the array, and look up  a dictionary, I don’t think it’ll wrap the dict in an immutable view automatically, which is an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution here is to provide a read-only "view" of your `_items` attribute. This is actually something that Python does by default with class dictionaries.

If I have a class `Foo`, like so:

```
class Foo:
    pass

f = Foo()
```

then you'll find that the *instance dictionary* of `f` (where the attributes for *that instance* are stored) and the *class dictionary* of `Foo` (where the attributes of the *class* are stored) are of different types.

```
>>> f.__dict__
{}
>>> Foo.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__doc__': None})
```

What's a `mappingproxy` object? Well, it's a readonly, dynamically updated, view of a dictionary. If we add an attribute to to `Foo`, the `mappingproxy` object is updated, but we can't mutate the `mappingproxy` object directly:

```
>>> cls_dict = Foo.__dict__
>>> 'bar' in cls_dict
False
>>> Foo.bar = 'baz'
>>> 'bar' in cls_dict
True
>>> cls_dict['baz'] = 'spam'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment
```

You can create your own `mappingproxy` objects yourself by importing `MappingProxyType` from the `types` module:

```
>>> from types import MappingProxyType
>>> mydict = {}
>>> mydict_proxy = MappingProxyType(mydict)
>>> mydict['spam'] = 'bar'
>>> mydict_proxy
mappingproxy({'spam': 'bar'})
>>> mydict_proxy['baz'] = 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment
```

Sadly, there isn't an equivalent `SequenceProxy` type in the Python standard library, which in my opinion would be useful for cases like this. However, it's fairly trivial to implement a `SequenceProxy` class, which means you could refactor your `Library` class like so:

```
import sys
import collections.abc
from typing import TypeVar, Sequence, Generic, Iterator, Union, Any

T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S', bound='SequenceProxy[Any]')

@collections.abc.Sequence.register
class SequenceProxy(Generic[T]):
    """Read-only proxy for a sequence.
    Similar in concept to `MappingProxyType`, but for sequences rather than mappings.
    """

    __slots__ = '_sequence',

    def __init__(self, initsequence: Sequence[T]) -> None:
        self._sequence = initsequence

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        return iter(self._sequence)

    def __getitem__(self: S, index: Union[int, slice]) -> Union[T, S]:
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return self.__class__(self._sequence[index])
        return self._sequence[index]

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._sequence)

    def __contains__(self, item: Any) -> bool:
        return item in self._sequence

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self._sequence!r})'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self._sequence)

    def __reversed__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        return reversed(self._sequence)

    def index(self, value: Any, start: int = 0, stop: int = sys.maxsize) -> int:
        """Return the index of a value in the underlying sequence."""
        return self._sequence.index(value, start, stop)

    def count(self, value: Any) -> int:
        """Return the number of times a value appears in the sequence."""
        return self._sequence.count(value)


class Library:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self._hours = []
        items = []
        self._items = items
        self._items_proxy = SequenceProxy(items)
        self._name = name
    
    def get_hours_str(self):
        ret = ""
        for day in self._hours:
            ret += day + '\n'
        return ret

    def get_items(self):
        return self._items_proxy
```

However, you should note that it is [generally considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/using-property-versus-getters-and-setters) more pythonic to use properties rather than "getter and setter" methods, meaning instead of your `get_items` method, you might do this:

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self._hours = []
        items = []
        self._items = items
        self._items_proxy = SequenceProxy(items)
        self._name = name
    
    def get_hours_str(self):
        ret = ""
        for day in self._hours:
            ret += day + '\n'
        return ret

    @property
    def items(self):
        return self._items_proxy
```

You can read more about the `@property` decorator -- how it works, and when to use it -- [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property).

Comment: I love your answer. Minor nitpick: it would be better to use [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) instead of hardcoding a specific value as the default for the `stop` argument to `index`.

Comment: @Jasmijn, excellent point — I've edited that in; thank you!

Comment: That's pretty nice.  Ever considered suggesting it as part of the standard library?  It doesn't seem like much of a stretch given the existence of `MappingProxyType`.

Comment: @JimmyJames, I've wondered about it! I guess I have a few qualms -- (1) Is there a strong enough use case for it? The core devs tend to be pretty conservative on new additions to the stdlib. (2) Would it be best to live in `types` or `collections`? `MappingProxyType` lives in `types`, but this style of code is *very* `collections`-y. (3) If the aim is to have something like `MappingProxyType`, but for sequences, should it be written in C, like `MappingProxyType`? I can see the argument that it might be misleading to have an optimised `MappingProxyType` but a pure-python `SequenceType`.

Comment: I think there's a good use case for it.  One of the weaknesses of Python IMO is its limited support for immutability.  I think this is especially true as Python's use cases continue to expand.  C versus pure?  I feel like we shouldn't care either way but maybe I'm missing something.  I'm not familiar with MappingProxyType and it's purpose but it seems odd that it's in types to me.  I don't think you'd really make that decision on your own though.

Comment: @JimmyJames I've taken the plunge https://discuss.python.org/t/feature-proposal-a-sequenceproxy-class/10442

Comment: @AlexWaygood If it's not accepted for some reason, this could be the seed of a decent library.  You could provide a decorator for these kinds of methods.  On that line of thinking, I searched for "proxy decorator python" and found [this](https://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrappers.html) but I'm not sure it's designed around the immutability use case.

Comment: @AlexWaygood Good note on the Pythonic way of handling things. Thanks for sharing this Proxy solution. I hadn't heard of this topic before.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are mixing up two concepts here:

- privacy of members of a class
- immutability of a class

In the code shown in the question, `self._items` is "truly private" in the usual Python sense of "privacy by convention", there is no method in `Library` which allows to change `self._items`. However, you correctly observed that the current implementation of `get_items` allows the caller of that method to modify the list itself - hence `Library` is not an immutable class any more.

Now in case you want that class to be immutable, you should change `get_items` either to return

- a full deep copy of the list (as you wrote by yourself)
- an iterator, as someone mentioned in the comments (examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542261))

Alternatively, one could also replace `get_items` by an index-based `get_item(self, index)` method, together with a `get_itemcount(self)` method.

For getting more information about when to make classes immutable or not, have a look into [this older SE.SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68058/at-what-point-do-immutable-classes-become-a-burden).

Comment: "Alternatively, one could also replace `get_items` by an index-based `get_item(self, index)` method, together with a `get_itemcount(self)` method." You usually don't want to do this, it is both less flexible and less convenient than using an iterator.

Comment: @Jasmijn: not necessarily, since it allows efficient access in random order without making a full copy, and there are scenarios where this can matter. For example, imagine there are 100000 library items, but your use case requires to pick only a few of them by their index. Try this with an iterator or a full copy of the list and compare the performance.

Comment: If that is a relevant use case, you're still better off returning a view object, which provides both iteration as well as random access.

Comment: @Jasmijn I think you trailed off: '... and indexed access'.  Also you can use such an object with `for` and `in` etc. instead of having to explicitly code around these custom method names.

Answer (score 2):

This is a semantical difference on what you mean by "X can modify Y".

If `myField` is private, but `SetMyField(newValue)` is public, you can argue whether or not another object is modifying the private field. Strictly speaking, it is not modifying the field. It is calling a function, and *that function* is the one modifying the private field.

*I used setting as an example here, but the same principle applies to getting.*

In other words, from a strict reading, "X can modify Y" is not equivalent to "X can call on Z to modify Y", but your question seems to equate the two.

This distinction matters, because "private" does not mean "inaccessible". It means "only accessible to the current class". Therefore, the decision to modify or return the value can still be made, but only inside that class. An outside actor cannot independently decide to modify/access the private field without its class explicitly providing a way for it to be modified/accessed.

> Would I need to make a "deep copy" of these in order for the items attribiute to be truly private?

While reference vs value types definitely influence the impact of what can happen to a returned value (i.e. a reference type object can be modified after only returning the reference to the object), this doesn't quite define the reasoning behind public and private access on a rudimentary level.

> Should I just make the attribute public?

This is arguable.

I'm no Python dev, so I'm not sure if you can make something publically gettable yet only privately settable. Assuming you can, and assuming that you *never* intend to *alter* the value when it is being retrieved, then there is little issue with making such a field publically gettable.

However, "never" is a big claim. Can you really account for all possible derived classes or future requirements? If you can, then what I said applies. But if you want to be careful about this, it's better to pass it through a getter method so that you retain the option of easily making alterations if or when you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I'm a little unsure why you would need a 'deep copy' in which not only is a new list created, each object in the list would need to be cloned as well.  If you don't want people to inadvertently modify the underlying list, a shallow copy i.e. list.copy() should be sufficient.  Only in the case where you are concerned that someone might modify the objects within the list that you should would need a 'deep copy'.  More information is [available here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) on the difference between the two.

So you need to determine whether it's the structure of the list that is of concern or the objects within the list as well.

Also, one other option to consider in your methods is using a generator:

```
def get_items(self):
    for item in self._items:
        yield item
```

On a side note, from a style perspective, prefixing `get` is a Java convention but I personally prefer plain `def items(self)` to return `self._items` here.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm concerned about the items in the list and the structure of the list (order doesn't matter but presence does).

Comment: @Cherise Are you concerned about which items are in the list or the state of those items.  There's a subtle distinction there that determines whether you really need a deep copy or a shallow copy.  For example, if your list is full of ints, a shallow copy should be fine because no one can change the value of say 0 to 1.  On the other hand, if this is a list of lists, a shallow copy would only protect the top level list and you would need a deep copy.

Comment: The state of the items within the list. Looks like a deep copy will do for now and I'll try to learn a bit more about the proxy solution later.

Comment: @Cherise The main concern I would have with `deepcopy()` is performance.  If your list is large, this could be problematic.  I don't think the proxy solution will protect the item state either, though.  You'd need to proxy each of the objects in the list as well.